# Android Gestures are not being Recognized but onGesturePerformed() is being called. How do I get different gestures to be recognized?

Tags: java, android, gesture, gestures, prediction

I'm trying to get this code to work:
http://scanplaygames.com/?p=168
(also on stackoverflow here):
[Adding GestureOverlayView to my SurfaceView class, how to add to view hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375967/adding-gestureoverlayview-to-my-surfaceview-class-how-to-add-to-view-hierarchy)

I ran the code and I added tags that print out the predictions.

```
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
    Log.d(TAG, predictions.toString());
```

...
After doing that, when I drew gestures an empty array would print out.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I know which gestures are being drawn?  How does this method work?

Also, could it be a problem with my gestures file?  I'm just not sure.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error may be in your use of predictions. It is an ArrayList so you have to get the first (0) one.

Try something like this:

```
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);

    // We want at least one prediction
    if (predictions.size() > 0) {
        Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);
        // We want at least some confidence in the result
        if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
            // Show the spell
            Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to see all the Predictions and so on just go over all the ArrayList.

Also in prediction.name you have the name you defined with the gesturesbuilder.